# Backing Store Size Does Not Match

Tags: qemu

I am trying to use ivshmem with QEMU and have thus set-up an ivshmem server. I start the server but when I try to spin up a VM with QEMU, I get the following error:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ivshmem-doorbell,vectors=1,chardev=testshm: backing store size 0x6300 does not match 'size' option 0x7000
```

This happens after my ivshmem server accepts the connection from QEMU and tries to send the shm fd to the QEMU VM. Where can I check the size of this so called backing store? How can I make it match?

This is the command I used to start the VM:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -initrd initrd.img-5.4.0-84-generic \
                        -kernel vmlinuz-5.4.0-84-generic \
                        -nographic -monitor none -serial stdio \ 
                        -append 'root=/dev/vda1 console=ttys0' \
                        -machine q35 -cpu host \
                        -drive "file=base.snapshot.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=virtio" \
                        -chardev socket,path="/run/testshm",id="testshm" \
                        -device ivshmem-doorbell,vectors=1,chardev="testshm" \
                        -enable-kvm \
                        -m 12G \
                        -smp 16
```

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the existing file before starting the VM.

`sudo rm /dev/shm/looking-glass` will do the trick.